# multiple plots in r with filter in r

Tags: r, plot, shiny

Good Morning,

Im trying to set up multiple plots with my code.
At the moment I can only plot one of the Checkbox Input Data

Does any1 has an Idea how I can change my server code so that it will plot multiple graphs in one plot?

Heres a Picture of my work atm
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6xcz.png

Thanks in advance

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Corona Testungszahlen"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel( h5("Hier koennen sie die Wochenspanne auswaehlen:"),
                      sliderInput("Wocheninput", "Kalenderwoche",11, 75, c(25, 40)),
                      uiOutput("slider"),
                      
                      checkboxGroupInput("plots", "Waehlen sie ihre Daten:", 
                                         choices=list("Anzahl_Testungen","Positiv_Getestet","Positivanteil_Prozent"), 
                                         selected="Anzahl_Testungen")),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("PLOT")
        )
    )
)


 server <- function(input, output) {
     output$PLOT <- renderPlot({
         filtered <-
             Daten %>%
             filter(Woche >= input$Wocheninput[1],
                    Woche <= input$Wocheninput[2]
             )
         ggplot(filtered, aes(Woche, .data[[input$plots]])) +
             geom_line(color="blue", size=1.2)
     })
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data in long format and filter for the columns that you want to plot. Specify the column name as `color` in ggplot code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

cols <- c("Anzahl_Testungen","Positiv_Getestet","Positivanteil_Prozent") 

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Corona Testungszahlen"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( h5("Hier koennen sie die Wochenspanne auswaehlen:"),
                  sliderInput("Wocheninput", "Kalenderwoche",11, 75, c(25, 40)),
                  uiOutput("slider"),
                  
                  checkboxGroupInput("plots", "Waehlen sie ihre Daten:", 
                                     choices=cols,
                                     selected="Anzahl_Testungen")),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("PLOT")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$PLOT <- renderPlot({
    filtered <-
      Daten %>%
      filter(Woche >= input$Wocheninput[1],
             Woche <= input$Wocheninput[2]
      ) %>%
      select(Woche, cols) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = -Woche) %>%
      filter(name %in% input$plots)
    
    ggplot(filtered, aes(Woche, value, color = name)) +
      geom_line(size=1.2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hey! :-) 

Thanks in advance! the Code worked! 
But I actually wanted the Data in one Graph :-D 
Now I got 3 Graphs side by side :-/